# Accept a parameter with same name but different value like Array/List in jersey rest webservice in java

Tags: java, jersey

I am having an html where i am generating input type text dynamically with same name 
Example:-

```
<form method="post"
    action="http://localhost:8080/social/rs/polling/temp"
    enctype="multipart/form-data"id="save_poll"
    id="save_poll">



    <input type="text" style="width: 400px; height: 31px; line-height: 31px;" class="answer_textbox" id="answer_textbox1" name="topic">

    <input type="text"  style="width: 400px; height: 31px; line-height: 31px;"  class="answer_textbox" id="answer_textbox2" name="topic">

    <input type="button" value="Save" id="save" >

</form>
```

Now, i am having a Jersey rest Service where i am gonna accept this textbox name "topic" ,
but i am not getting how to do that?
i tried getting it by using list of string like ,@FormDataParam("topic") List topic, and also by array of string like, @FormDataParam("topic") String []  topic
but still i unable to get those textbox fields,
The error i am getting while using List of string is "wrong number of arguement",
and for array of string i am getting null in topic array?
Please help?

Comment: can u share ur jersey web service class code?

Comment: here it is:- http://pastie.org/8379496

Comment: your web service code is correct, check your client? try to send the same request using another client such as jmeter